# SetEnvironmentVariable error

Tags: c++

so I recently installed Visual Studio 2013 for C++(I've been using VS 2010 earlier), but when trying to compile i get theese errors:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets(214,5): error : The source file for this compilation can be found at: "C:\Users\Ägaren\AppData\Local\Temp\76067da3-a8a0-451b-ba32-8a9d634384fe.txt"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets(214,5): error MSB3758: An error has occurred during compilation. error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Users\Ägaren\AppData\Local\Temp\mis2a4kb.dll' -- 'Could not execute CVTRES.EXE.'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets(214,5): error MSB4036: The "SetEnvironmentVariable" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin" directory.
```

There's to much code for me to show you my entire code, but here's the entirety of main.cpp (The file PMemory is a RPM & WPM Class, Game.h is a file with a struct)

Here's my main.cpp:

```
#include "Game.h"


#pragma region offsets
DWORD offLocalPlayer;
DWORD offEntityList;
const DWORD offEntityTeam = 0xF0;

DWORD offGlow;
#pragma endregion

#pragma region globalVars
PModule modClient;
PMemory mem;
#pragma endregion

#pragma region hotKeys
int whichKeyIsPressed() {
    while (true) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 0x8000) {
                while (GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 0x8000) {
                    Sleep(50);
                }
                return i;
            }
        }
        Sleep(10);
    }
}
int keyGlowToggle;
#pragma endregion

void ReadData(Player* p) {
    p->team = mem.Read<int>(p->dwBase + offEntityTeam);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Testing...\n\n";
    std::cout << "Waiting for csgo.exe...";
    while (!mem.Attach("csgo.exe")) {
        std::cout << ".";
        Sleep(500);
    }
    modClient = mem.GetModule("client.dll");
    std::cout << "\nFound\n\n";

    std::cout << "Getting offsets...";
    // Glow offset
    DWORD gpStart = mem.FindPatternArr(modClient.dwBase, modClient.dwSize, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx????xxxxxxx", 25, 0x6B, 0xD6, 0x34, 0x89, 0x44, 0x0A, 0x30, 0x8D, 0x8F, 0xE4, 0x1B, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA1, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC7, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
    offGlow = mem.Read<DWORD>(gpStart + 14) - modClient.dwBase;

    // Entity list
    DWORD elStart = mem.FindPatternArr(modClient.dwBase, modClient.dwSize, "x????xx?xxx", 11, 0x5, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xC1, 0xE9, 0x0, 0x39, 0x48, 0x4);
    DWORD elP1 = mem.Read<DWORD>(elStart + 1);
    BYTE elP2 = mem.Read<BYTE>(elStart + 7);
    offEntityList = (elP1 + elP2) - modClient.dwBase;

    // Local player
    DWORD lpStart = mem.FindPatternArr(modClient.dwBase, modClient.dwSize, "xxx????xx????xxxxx?", 19, 0x8D, 0x34, 0x85, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x89, 0x15, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x8B, 0x41, 0x8, 0x8B, 0x48, 0x0);
    DWORD lpP1 = mem.Read<DWORD>(lpStart + 3);
    BYTE lpP2 = mem.Read<BYTE>(lpStart + 18);
    offLocalPlayer = (lpP1 + lpP2) - modClient.dwBase;

    std::cout << "\nDone\n\n";

    std::cout << "Hotkeys: \n";
    std::cout << "Toggle glow: ";
    keyGlowToggle = whichKeyIsPressed();
    std::cout << keyGlowToggle << "\n";
    std::cout << "\n";

    bool glowEnabled = false;
    Player me;
    Player players[64];

    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)) {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(keyGlowToggle) & 0x8000) {
            while (GetAsyncKeyState(keyGlowToggle) & 0x8000) {
                Sleep(50);
            }
            glowEnabled = !glowEnabled;
            std::cout << "Glow ESP is now ";
            if (glowEnabled) {
                std::cout << "enabled\n";
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "disabled\n";
            }
        }

        if (glowEnabled) {
            me.dwBase = mem.Read<DWORD>(modClient.dwBase + offLocalPlayer);
            ReadData(&me);
            for (int i = 1; i < 64; i++) {
                players[i].dwBase = mem.Read<DWORD>(modClient.dwBase + offEntityList + i * 0x10);
                ReadData(&players[i]);
            }

            DWORD pointerGlow = mem.Read<DWORD>(modClient.dwBase + offGlow);
            int objectCount = mem.Read<int>(modClient.dwBase + offGlow + 0x4);
            if (pointerGlow != NULL) {
                for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++) {
                    DWORD mObj = pointerGlow + i * sizeof(GlowObjectDefinition_t);
                    GlowObjectDefinition_t glowObj = mem.Read<GlowObjectDefinition_t>(mObj);
                    if (glowObj.pEntity != NULL) {
                        int f_i = -1;
                        for (int j = 1; j < 64; j++) {
                            if (glowObj.pEntity == players[j].dwBase) {
                                int r = 255, g = 0, b = 0;
                                if (players[j].team == me.team) {
                                    r = 0;
                                    b = 255;
                                }
                                mem.Write<float>(mObj + 0x4, r / 255);
                                mem.Write<float>(mObj + 0x8, g / 255);
                                mem.Write<float>(mObj + 0xC, b / 255);
                                mem.Write<float>(mObj + 0x10, 1.0f);
                                mem.Write<BOOL>(mObj + 0x24, true);
                                mem.Write<BOOL>(mObj + 0x25, false);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I do not know what else to type here, as I have no idea why this errors is popping up, my friends tell me it might be something blocking Visual studio, or me not having access, but I've checked all of theese options. VS has full access to Adminstator, and there is nothing blocking it.

Comment: Is there a file already in the temp directory? Sometimes an old file from a previous build has locks on it and cannot be overwritten. Telling it to do a complete rebuild usually clears this.

Comment: They are completely nonsensical error messages.  At least MSBuild did not install properly, there's probably more wrong.  You need to thoroughly check your hard drive for damage and reinstall.

Comment: @HansPassant Alright, I'll test reinstalling VS 2013.

Comment: Don't just reinstall, you almost certainly have disk damage.  The content of the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets file is garbage.  Ask for help at superuser.com if necessary.

Comment: _"There's to much code for me to show you my entire code, but here's the entirety of main.cpp"_ Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mvce.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Page not found"

Comment: Sorry http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a fresh installed VS2017 on Win10 platform. The reason is that the current account doesn't have the privelege to generate a temp source code file to the ‘%WINROOT/temp’ folder.

I solved this problem by running the VS2017 to build the project under the ‘Administrator’ account once, and wiredly found out that everthing goes fine after I returned to my regular user account (with administrative privelege).

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Edit environment for your account" and set the vars `TEMP` and `TMP` to this value:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Restart Visual Studio.